# Distinguishing Unique Device Connections

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am running a QR scavenger hunt, where users will signup with the first scan page, and then go find the other QR codes.  I want to automatically recognize the person on return (scanning further QR codes) based on the device they are using (which I will save as a key into a cloud database (Azure) during signup.

How can I uniquely identify devices?  I'm familiar with identifying devices based on getting the IP address and/or name, but am only aware how to do that on a single domain, as follows:

```
//Get Client Machine name to restrict login
string[] computer_name = System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(Request.ServerVariables["remote_addr"]).HostName.Split(new Char[] { '.' });
string ecn = System.Environment.MachineName;
string strClientName = computer_name[0].ToString();
```

I then compare strClientName (which is unique on our domain).

What's a good way to do this considering the client may connect from any network, domain, etc?  I have considered using something like MAC Address, but I don't see a good way to get that, and am not sure if it will always be unique.  Technically, I don't care if this is 100% accurate (as the group will likely be no more than 100 people), but I'd like something that will scale eventually.

I'd prefer a C# solution to run on Page_Load, but can also implement a javascript or jQuery solution.  I expect the bulk of the users to be using any variety of random QR apps on iPhones and Droids, along with a few win phones.  The QR code will point them to a web address running my .NET project.

Comment: Assuming the device is using a browser to contact your server, why not just create a unique cookie in their first connection and use that to identify which device it is from then on.  That, for example, is how a site lets you create a shopping cart if you aren't logged in.  You can create the cookie on either client or server if it doesn't exist.

Comment: @jfriend00 do you know if this even works within QR scanning apps?  I'll have to try later today and let you know.

Comment: No, you didn't say what specific application you are using or how it works.  My comment was assuming you were using browser technology.  If you're confined to a specific non-browser application, then you HAVE to disclose that application and probably do some research on how it works and its capabilities.  How else could we know how to help here?

Comment: I'm sorry, I was implying it by saying people would be scanning QR codes, but there are other ways.  I'll update my question, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer assumes the following process.  The user fires up a QR code scanning app (probably on a phone or tablet, but it doesn't matter what kind of device).  They scan the QR code and the QR app then loads that URL in the local device's browser.  Every QR code goes to your same domain (different URL, but all on the same domain).

In this world, you can use a cookie to uniquely identify each device.  When you first see a hit from any device that does not have a particular cookie associated with it, your server can coin a unique cookie and return it with the web request.  If you give the cookie a path of `'/'`, then, all future QR hits from that device will return that same cookie so it can be your device identifier.  This type of identifier will identify the browser and be independent of any network changes as the device moves around to different locations or networks.

A simple method of coining a unique cookie value is to create a string from a time stamp combined with a random number.

The device can be reinitialized at any time by clearing cookies on the device or you can make a web page that offers a button to clear that particular cookie for them.

Comment: Thanks, this works great!  In case anyone else runs across this, I checked for the cookie using HttpCookie cookie = Request.Cookies.Get("CookieName");
then if it is null, I create the cookie using cookie = new HttpCookie("CookieName"); , then give cookie a value and expiration date, then return it with the response.  Otherwise I get the value from the cookie.

Comment: @Jem - Glad it works.  Make sure you set the cookie path to `'/'` so you can access the cookie from anywhere on your site.

Comment: that seems to be the default path (when I drill down into the cookie settings), so it's working great!  Now I just need to get my DB connection strings setup.  Having some issues connecting to Azure (first-time).  I'll get it eventually :)